# Is there a way where we can set system environment variables separately for each App while deploying the stream

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

We are using a third part security library which requires a system environment variable to be set. Can we pass as parameter in stream definition or while deploying stream separately for each app?

Comment: Which dataflow-server implementation are you using? Also, are you consuming the maven or docker app artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this myself, but it looks like you can set the desired environment variable for the Spring Cloud Data Flow Server and then also add it to [`spring.cloud.deployer.local.envVarsToInherit`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-application-configuration).